# How to get the items from adapter and store it in list?

Tags: android, android-layout, arraylist, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

I am getting list from `adapter` which is working fine. Now I need to store it in the list in `MainActivity` on button click. But I am getting crash as,

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.savedayreq.RoutePlanDayRequests.setPartnerId(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
>                                                                                 at com.view.RoutePlanVisitChangeActivity$2.onClick(RoutePlanVisitChangeActivity.java:92)

line number 92 is this code.

```
 submitChangeRequest.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                adapter = (RoutePlanVisitChangeAdapter) mRecyclerView.getAdapter();
                List<RoutePlanDayRequests> routePlanDayRequests=null;
                RoutePlanDayRequests requests = null;
                for (int i = 0; i < adapter.getItemCount(); i++) {
                    Retailers selectedView = adapter.getItem(i);

                    View dataView  = mRecyclerView.getChildAt(i);
                    Spinner toDaySpinner = (Spinner) dataView.findViewById(R.id.to_day);
                      //i can print this oldDay,newDay, msisdn line..
                    String oldDay = selectedView.getRoutePlanDayOfWeek(); 
                    String newDay = toDaySpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
                    String msisdn = selectedView.getMsisdn(); //i can also print this line in log. 
        //***But I am getting crash from this line no 92..*** 
                    requests.setPartnerId(selectedView.getMsisdn());
                    requests.setParentPartnerId(selectedView.getMsisdn());
                    requests.setApproverId("1");
                    requests.setStatus("0");
                    requests.setRetailerPrmId(selectedView.getMsisdn());
                    requests.setOldDay(oldDay);
                    requests.setNeweDay(newDay);
                    routePlanDayRequests.add(requests); 
                    updateServiceList(AppUtils.getMsisdn(mSharedPreferences),routePlanDayRequests);
}
```

Comment: `RoutePlanDayRequests requests = null` is the problem

Comment: This is fundamental JAVA knowledge that you are lacking. Initialize both of the null objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not initializing these 2 objects. They are set to null.

```
List<RoutePlanDayRequests> routePlanDayRequests=null;
RoutePlanDayRequests requests = null;
```

Initialize both of them like this -

```
List<RoutePlanDayRequests> routePlanDayRequests= new Arraylist();
RoutePlanDayRequests requests = new RoutePlanDayRequests();
```

You'll need a public constructor for you `RoutePlanDayRequests`. In you `RoutePlanDayRequests` class add this constructor.

```
public RoutePlanDayRequests() {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should make a new object from RoutePlanDayRequests and then you can set this object's variables
change this line :

```
 RoutePlanDayRequests requests = null
```

to

```
RoutePlanDayRequests requests = new RoutePlanDayRequests()
```

if RoutePlanDayRequests has empty cunstructor

Answer (score 0):

**Initialise**   this   `RoutePlanDayRequests` class

```
  RoutePlanDayRequests requests = new RoutePlanDayRequests();
```